# What are these components in these circuits?

Tags: components, identification

I have seen a documentary about making [BGM-71 TOW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGM-71_TOW) (an anti-tank missile - the Iranians make it). You can see it in this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRkkwmHH7QU) (part 1). I have seen two odd components. In your opinion, what are these components?

The first component is this (at 4:17 minute):

[image]

The second component is this (at 4:38 minute):

[image]

Here's another picture of the second component (at 4:50 minute):

[image]

Comment: The second component kind of looks like a large wattage resistor. The first, I don't have a clue.

Comment: I think it is just a stamp. I watched the video at that point and if you see how it is applied, it doesn't look like a component.

Comment: this^ that looks like a stamp to me too

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to see from the photos but the second component doesn't look like a resistor to me, but a plated metal enclosure rather like those used to package crystals, only larger.

What's inside it? Not a clue, but my guess would be a SAW filter or crystal filter, physically large enough to need such a case.

These sometimes come in [odd packages](http://www.qrbiz.com/product/846349/SAW-filter.html).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I could not find any crystals large enough to fit the bill. It could be, as you said, just a metal enclosure for something else.

Comment: There certainly WERE larger crystals in use in the west (WW11 era) but my suspicion is something composite (filter : possibly RF mixer?) rather than a single element.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the same package for 32.768khz crystal but this is so much big.